# Let R be a principal ideal ring, prove R is a Noetherian ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, principal-ideal-domains, noetherian

Let R be a principal ideal ring, prove R is a Noetherian ring. know we have to construct an ascending chain of principal ideals in R. And take their union, this is obviously an ideal. Since R is a PID, this union is a principal ideal. Zorn's lemma implies there exists a maximal element of the ascending chain. This will be equal to the ideal which is the union.
Part I do not understand is Zorn's Lemma.

Suppose a partially ordered set  has the property that every chain (i.e. totally ordered subset) has an upper bound in . Then the set  contains at least one maximal element.

My question is existence of upper bound for every chain of ideals and how that union is the maximal in chain/

Comment: So your question is that you wonder why Zorn's Lemma is true?

Comment: I need detail explanation about it.

Comment: Can this be done simpler, without Zorn's Lemma? My algebra is a bit rusty but ... You have an ascending chain of ideals $a_1R\subset a_2R\subset a_3R\subset\ldots$ and $\bigcup_{i\in \mathbb N}a_iR=aR$ for some $a$ (being an ideal). Then $a$ must already belong to some $a_iR$, so $aR=a_iR$ and all but finitely many of those ideals $a_iR$ are equal (to $aR$ and to each other).

Comment: Are you rereading some somewhat garbled notes?  Ascending chains are involved, but Zorn's lemma does not seem necessary. Also you do not have to *construct* an ascending chain, you need to *prove something about ascending chains*.

Comment: This is correct; Zorn's lemma is not needed. More generally, a similar argument shows that $R$ is Noetherian if every ideal is only finitely generated, rather than principal.  (Of course every ideal of a Noetherian ring is finitely generated as well).

Comment: @Keon What's your definition of "noetherian"?  Ideals satisfy the ascending chain condition? Ideals satisfy maximal condition?  That may have something to do with involving Zorn's lemma.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends heavily on what your definition of "Noetherian" is. Are you working with the ascending chain condition on ideals?

If you start with an infinite nondecreasing chain $A_i\subseteq A_{i+1}$ of proper ideals (in a ring with identity), then $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i=(a)$ is a proper ideal containing all the $A_i$'s.

But $a\in A_j$ for some $j$, and that would mean that $(a)\subseteq A_j$.  In that case, $A_j=\bigcup A_i=A_k$ for every $k\geq j$.

This says that all such chains stabilize, that is, the ring satisfies the ascending chain condition on ideals.

The same reasoning shows you that if you just suppose all ideals are finitely generated, then the ascending chain condition holds.

---

Are you using the maximum condition on ideals?

I think, perhaps, it was intended for you to use Zorn's Lemma to prove that ACC on ideals implies this.  For if you are given a nonempty set of ideals of $R$, Zorn's lemma and the ACC together imply that every chain in the set is bounded, and hence the whole set has a maximal element.

The converse implication (maximal condition implies ACC) always holds, of course: given any chain, the maximal condition implies the chain has a greatest element, and that would make the chain stable.

---

Despite the name, Zorn's Lemma is just the Axiom of Choice in another guise. You are free to assume it holds, or not, and we often assume it.  Using it is easy: if its hypotheses are satisfied, then its conclusion holds.  To do this, you need to validate that ascending chains in a poset are bounded in that set, and then you magically get a maximal element somewhere in the poset.

Comment: Can you also tell me how we can use Zorn's lemma here.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you need the axiom of countable choice to say that the ascending chain condition implies that every ideal is finitely generated or that every non-empty set of ideals contains a maximal element. I'm pretty sure you don't need the axiom for the converse.

Comment: If the union is not proper, then some $A_j$ contains a unit, no?

Comment: Yes... hrm, I may be off my coffee here... yes, rereading what Trevor wrote, that sounds right: Zorn's needed for the converse.  Or possibly it is because the poster only has the definition using the maximal condition and not the ACC, so maybe it is needed to bridge those two.

Comment: I do not understand "Zorn's lemma and the ACC together imply that every chain in the set is bounded, and hence the whole set has a maximal element."

Comment: Zorn's lemma implies there exists a maximal element of the ascending chain. This will be equal to the ideal which is the union. Every ascending chain has an upper bound

Comment: @Keon No, you are misquoting Zorn’s lemma.   It says IF every chain has an upper bound THEN there is a maximal element _somewhere in the poset_.  It does not say anything about an element of the chain being maximal.

Comment: I agree, this is what I understand now, and I am not sure about upper bound

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable time.

Comment: @Keon No problem. Zorn's lemma is a little weird to think about at first, but after you apply it in a few different scenarios, it gets clearer.

Comment: Is this true that every chain has an upper bound?

Comment: Not in every poset, no.  For example, the poset of rationals $-1/n$ in the open interval $(-1,0)$ form a strictly ascending chain with no upper bound in the poset.

Comment: I somehow think that union is an upper bound in any chain. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Keon The "union" in the chain I presented is the supremum. The supremum of the chain is $0$ which is not in the poset.  You're right that in the full poset of ideals of a ring, the union of any chain of ideals is an upper bound for that chain.  In some applications, it is not true, though. For example, if your poset is the chain of proper ideals, then it is not immediately clear whether or not the union is _a proper ideal._ . It is true for rings with identity, using Zorn.

Comment: zero? From where?

Comment: Poset: $\{-1/n\mid n\in\mathbb N^+\}$ with its natural ordering in $\mathbb R$. The elements, in the indexing I gave them, are a strictly ascending infinite chain (also a poset) with no upper bound _in the poset_.